# Angular ui-route reload current controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got a problem with reload current state.

Can i reload current state only reload the content?.

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/dashboard');
    .state('app', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/app',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: '/app/content.html'
                },
                'sidebar': {
                    templateUrl: '/app/sidebar.html'
                },
            },
        })
     .state('app.categories', {
        url: '/categories',
        templateUrl: '/app/category/category.html',
        resolve: {
            loadJs: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load('/app/category/category.app.js');
            }]
        }
    })
```

If i'm on the categories site, and call

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
```

I want only the main section (see picture).

[image: picture]

Right now it reload entire state. The problem if it reload entire state all my navigation (left side) break.

My current html:

```
<div class="left side-menu"  ng-controller="AppCtrl" ui-view="sidebar@"></div>


<div class="content-page">
    <!-- Start content -->
    <div class="content" ui-view>

    </div>

</div> <!-- content -->
```

How can I do it?

Comment: ui.router reload will reload all pages and yes you are right it won't help you but why you want to reload only that state maybe we can find another solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, {}, {reload: 'app.categories'});
```